# C++: system(0) Returns 0

Tags: c++, shell, system

When I call *system(0)* it returns 0, which means *shell is not available*.

When a command using *system* (calls gcc to compile a hello world program), it works just fine but returns -1 (I assume it's the same cause as for *system(0)* returning 0). What causes it to be "not available" and why does it work anyway?

Compiler: *gcc version 4.6.1 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3)*

OS: Ubuntu 11.10

**EDIT**

Errno says *No Child Processes*.

I have also compiled another test program that does not do anything but calls *system(0)* and it returns nonzero value. Can it be affected by Code::Blocks?

**EDIT**

So far I have figured out that *system(0)* only fails after I start my first pthread.

**SOLVED**

I used *fork* in my early implementation of one of this piece of code:

```
signal(SIGCHLD,SIG_IGN);
```

I used it to "handle" zombies. I just found out that this caused the error.

Comment: @Paul : calling `system` with argument `0` is basically a test to see if the shell is available. eg. "If command is a null pointer, the system() function shall determine whether the host environment has a command processor."

Comment: @Sander: thanks - I didn't know that - I just re-read the man page and I see you're right !

Comment: @Paul, from system(3) documentation: "If the value of command is NULL, system() returns nonzero if the shell is available, and zero if not."

Comment: @Pius : what's `errno` set to after running `system(your_command)` ?

Comment: Updated question with errno info.

Comment: @Pius : do you have any handler for the `SIGCHLD` signal ? Or are you ignoring the `SIGCHLD` signal using `signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);` ?

Comment: @Pius : given your recent edit, I guess I'll post my previous comment as an answer then ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could happen if you are ignoring the `SIGCHLD` signal using code like :

```
signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);
```

This would cause `system` to return `-1` when all children have ended, setting `errno` to `ECHILD`.

Refer to http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/wait.html. Specifically :

> If the calling process has SA_NOCLDWAIT set or has SIGCHLD set to SIG_IGN, and the process has no unwaited-for children that were transformed into zombie processes, the calling thread shall block until all of the children of the process containing the calling thread terminate, and wait() and waitpid() shall fail and set errno to [ECHILD].

Comment: `no unwaited-for` -> I gave +1 to your post since it is not your mistake, but that expression would need an overhaul to be easily understandable by non-native speakers.

Answer (score 1):

Man says:

> The value returned is -1 on error (e.g. fork(2) failed), and the return status of the command otherwise. This latter return status is in the format specified in wait(2). Thus, the exit code of the command will be WEXITSTATUS(status). In case /bin/sh could not be executed, the exit status will be that of a command that does exit(127). If the value of command is NULL, system() returns nonzero if the shell is available, and zero if not.

If you have no `sh` in your path or is not an executable is not available. Check your configuration.

If system returns -1 may be a problem executing `fork`, so check `errno` variable value or maybe the return status of the invoked command, that may be also -1. Verify exit status of your command executed from chell.

Comment: Well, the command I was executing was gcc compiling a Hello World program. It compiles just fine and outputs nothing (tried with syntax errors - gcc does it's job and outputs everything). The thing I am worrying about is that shell is not available for some reason. Normally system(0) should return nonzero value.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. You are executing a program with a `system`sentence inside against gcc. Something like `system("gcc -o foo foo.cpp")`. Is that true? In this case, `system` returns `gcc` return value: 0 if ok

Comment: Yes. BUT it does not return 0. It returns -1 for the command call (means system functions failed (but it didn't)). I get 0 from system(0) which (by manual) means that shell is not available. After THIS (system(0)) call errno is "No Child Processes".

Comment: @Pius, edit your question adding your code and comment it with errors.

Comment: I have no code to show because at some points system(0) starts returning 0 instead of 1 and I still can't seem to find the exact peace of code that is causing that.