# Linux C++ program launching a bash script via system call always returns -1

Tags: c++, linux, bash, system

I have a chain of programs as follows:

C++ program "A" launches another C++ program "B" which launches a bash script.

To launch the bash script, I am using:

```
int returnVal = system("pathToScript/myScript.sh");
```

I can see the output of the script in my log file, so it's definitely being executed.

Problem is, returnVal is always -1 no matter what the script returns. I even hard coded an "exit 3" in the script and I'm still getting a returnVal of -1 when I launch it via the system call.

Running the script standalone in a terminal and echoing "$?" shows a return value of 3 as expected.

So why is the exit code breaking when I run it through a chain of C++ programs? Is there any way to get around this?

**EDIT** - Using perror shows a "No child processes" error message.

**EDIT** - As an alternative, I'm trying to use fork/exec/wait to execute my script, but I'm getting random exit codes such as 182, 56, 163, 62, 51, etc... Code below:

```
pid_t pid = vfork();

switch (pid)
{
  case -1:
     cout << "Failed to fork." << endl;

  case 0: // Child process
     cout << "Child process launched!" << endl;
     execl("/pathToScript/myScript.sh", "/pathToScript/myScript.sh", "someArgument", NULL);
     cout << "execl call failed." << endl;
     exit(0);

  default:
     int status;

     cout << "Waiting for process to complete..." << endl;

     waitpid(pid, &status, 0); // Wait for the process to complete.

     cout << "Process exited with status: " << WEXITSTATUS(status) << endl;
}
```

Why am I getting random exit status here?

Appreciate any advice. Thanks!

Comment: From `man system` - "The value returned is -1 on error". Can you print out `perror ("")` message?

Comment: The error is "No child processes".

Comment: Hmmm, read this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9080311/10077

Comment: If you shure, that your script executed, then as pointed @Fred Larson - problem should be with ignoring `SIGCHLD`.

Comment: If I do a "signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_DFL)" before executing the system call it works. Is this a global setting though? I fear that I might be breaking something else in the program (it's a huge program) by doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments your problem is ignorig `SIGCHLD`.
Ignoring `SIGCHLD` can be used to prevent the creation of zombies.
So by setting it disposition to default **you can break something.**

*Here example:*

```
signal (SIGCHLD, SIG_DFL);
system ("some_program");
signal (SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);
```

*If some child process (not child in `system`) terminated between execution first and third line, it will become a zombie.*

If you want solve this resources leak correctly, you should use another method (double `fork` or `wait`) for solving zombies problem.

---

> Why am I getting random exit status here?

**Because `waitpid` call failed.** If you print out return value of `waitpid` it will be `-1`. The value of `errno` most likely will be `ECHILD`. Setting disposition of `SIGCHLD` to `SIG_IGN` causes breaking `wait` and `waitpid`. In your example `waitpid` writes nothing to `status` variable (or writes trash).

> 182, 56, 163, 62, 51, etc..

**This numbers are values of uninitialized integer variable (or trash).**

> As an alternative, I'm trying to use fork/exec/wait to execute my script

**It is not good alternative.** Alternative solution is set disposition of `SIGCHLD` to `SIG_DFL` for all parts of program. And change strategy of handling zombies in other parts.

Comment: If I leave SIG_DFL on, and I execute the system call periodically (say every 10 seconds), shouldn't I see the process table grow? I'm looking at top and also the ps list and it's not growing at all.

Comment: @user1464652 If you want just play around with code and your changes not cause any troubles - i think it's ok. But if you want write good program you should think about changing strategy of solving zombies problem.

Comment: I updated the original post with some fork/exec/wait code. But it's giving me random exit status each time it's executed. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. It is my understanding that the SIG_IGN handler in program "B" is being inherited from program "A". That would explain why I can run program "B" standalone and not get this problem, since it uses SIG_DFL by default. Program "B" only uses the system command to launch a script here and there, so I think it should be safe to use SIG_DFL here. Correct me if I'm wrong, but the system command will use wait to get the exit code so the zombies will be removed. And of course, program "A" can be left to use SIG_IGN.