# system() returns non-zero but still performs action

Tags: c, linux

I'm using the `system` command to gzip some log files:

```
if (system("gzip -f log.csv"))
{
      printf("gzip failed");
      return;  
}
```

Occasionally (very inconsistently), I'll get a `gzip failed` message, which exits the function and doesn't perform some other tasks that are contingent on the gzip being successful. When I go examine the directory at the command-line, however, the file was indeed gzipped correctly into `log.csv.gz` (i.e. I can `gunzip` it -- the command apparently did not fail even though `system` returned a non-zero value).

How is this possible? Am I just missing something?

Comment: Look at what gzip writes to stderr when it happens. I don't know how you'd expect us to tell you anything useful without logs.

Comment: ...it could be, for instance, that your implementation of gzip exits with an error status if anything else changes its input file during operation (since that would mean that it couldn't be sure that the compressed version exactly matched any version of the input).

Comment: BTW, I hope your real program is hardcoding the log name (as you are here) rather than substituting any arbitrary filename into a `system()` call. Think about what would happen if you had a file created with `touch '$(rm -rf ~)'`, and substituted that name into a call to `system()`. (Quoting can make that a *little* harder to execute, but it can only be fully avoided with escaping... or doing the Right Thing and calling your intended external programs via a proper fork()/exec() with arguments passed in an array, not all munged in a single string to be parsed out by a shell).

Comment: this, from the man page for `system()` may explain what your seeing: *The value returned is -1 on  error  (e.g.,  fork(2)  failed),  and  the
       return  status  of the command otherwise.  This latter return status is
       in the format specified in wait(2).  Thus, the exit code of the command
       will  be  WEXITSTATUS(status).   In case /bin/sh could not be executed,
       the exit status will be that of a command that does exit(127).*

Answer (score 4):

According to this [guide](http://www.moundalexis.com/tm/2009/12/24/return-code-for-common-utilities/), gzip returning with an exit code of 2 means it had a warning. This means it probably produced an output but maybe not correctly?

Comment: Actually, the problem came back. See my answer below -

Answer (score 3):

There is **absolutely no requirement** that a program with a nonzero exit status roll back all actions it performed prior to the error resulting in that status. In fact, such an action would often be either impossible or destructive.

As such, it is entirely possible for any command to return a nonzero exit status but still to have an effect on system state.

Comment: There's another option too - that the command executed just fine, but that `system()` itself is returning an error. See my answer -

Comment: Heh. If you'd indicated the specific return value, might have been able to get there. In any event, good find.

Answer (score 1):

I did a little more investigation, and it appears that the root cause of the gzip failures seemed to be a race condition between two waidpid calls: the one in system() itself, and the other in a custom SIGCHLD handler that somewhere else in the code (this is a huge multi-thousand line process).

If the child (gzip) is harvested by the custom SIGCHLD handler, then system() returns -1 (since its waidpid fails), otherwise system() returns 0 as expected.

This is the SO post that helped me ultimately solve it:

[C++: system(0) Returns 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9080311/c-system0-returns-0)